# How to Track the Changes in every textbox and checkboxes and radio buttons in a forms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a form which has checkboxes, textboxes, comboboxes and radiobuttons. and I have a save button which will save the values of the above controls into the database.
Now I need to store the old value and controls and new values. that means need to store the history of changes in database. Im using WPF form and controls.

Any Idea?

Comment: What is the definition of `change` in this terms? If a user uncheck the checkbox and then re-check it again, will it be counted as a change, or not?

Comment: @Tanya You have many questions that you have not selected an answer on. I would recommend that you go back and select one for the ones that has been answered. It is a simple way to help the stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of 'flags' for each control on your form. 
handle change events of the controls, and if value is modified set the flag. 
on Save button click, you can check if any flags are set, then you can save changes the way you want.

Comment: when loading the controls, that change event is happening

Answer (score 0):

if u want to maintain the history of your update row use trigger on update.and store old value to your history table .

Comment: no both r different trigger used in database. what database u r using in your application.give us more relevant info what u want to achive so i will able to give u some example link to achieve your task.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to have a before and after of the values changed on a form.  So let's say you were saving a person's contact information. When you load up this contact information you could make a copy of the class.  Then when you click save, check the two instances to see what is different and save that in your history table.